# How to enable `sorttable.js` on Rails4 with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, sorttable.js

- Rails 4.2.0, turbolinks (2.5.3)
- jquery-rails (4.0.3), jquery-ui-rails (5.0.3)
- [`sorttable.js`](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)
- App used on Chrome, Firefox, and IE

**WHAT SHOULD HAPPEN**: Whether a redirect, render, or just clicking to a new page in the app, any table with class `sorttable` (I edited it in the original JS) should be sortable by column heading.

**WHAT ACTUALLY HAPPENS**: I am on a contacts page. I hit refresh, and logger statements in the JS appear. The plugin works as expected. If I navigate to Home, then back to Contacts, the file is still listed in the page source, but no logger statements appear. The plugin does not work.

Our `application.js` reads as such:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require bootstrap
//= require sorttable
//= require_directory .
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-switch
```

Disabling Turbolinks per-page or altogether is not a solution for us. I am open to using gems if the file just does not work with turbolinks; however, the gem should add little code to the app. We'd rather not have classes dedicated to choosing which column to sort. Also, some columns to-be-sorted are not from ActiveRecord (like 2 attributes in 1 cell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much debugging, I figured out why turbolinks does not like `sorttable.js`. The JS file includes triggers (some based on browser type) to initiate sorttable on document load. Such event listener is incompatible with turbolinks. What I have done to make this work is the following.

1. Move `vendor/assets/javascripts/sorttable.js` to `app/views/shared/js/_sorttable.html.haml`
2. Prefix the new file with `:javascript` (`%script{languauge: "javascript"}`), and indent all following lines 2 spaces
3. Remove sorttable from `application.js`
4. At the top of all related pages, add the following code block:

   ```
   = render 'shared/js/sorttable'
   %script
     $(document).on("page:change", sorttable.init)
   ```

For code examples and further explanation, please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/onebree/efdf56929f63012ac85e).