# Sort table data by columns in rails with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

**Edit**: I would prefer to using bootstrap for this functionality if possible since I have bootstrap in my project.  It seems like I might just be missing something to utilize bootstrap's javascript within my rails project.

When the column name is clicked, the table should sort the data by that column name. Below is the table:

[image]

I attempted to sort the data with bootstrap, following  the examples shown [at this website](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#sort-table), but it wasn't working for me. What am I missing?

Relevant gems in my Gemfile:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

CSS:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Javascript:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

View displaying records:

```
#app/views/index.html.erb
<h4>Listing Users</h4>

<table class=" table table-striped" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-field="age" data-sortable="true">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.age %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

Comment: The example shows that `data-sortable="true"` is given `<th>`. Try giving `data-sortable="true"` for `<th>` in your code and remove it for `<td>`.

Comment: @Pavan that was a typo mistake when moving the code over to stack overflow.  Unfortunately it still is not working for me.

Comment: Try adding `//= require jquery-ui/sortable` to your `apllication.js`

Comment: @Pavan I attempted installing the `jquery-ui-rails` gem and added the jquery-ui stuff in the javascript and css files, but still did not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to a lot of feedback from [Hunter Stevens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31484227/3373470). Best option I found for me was to use `sorttable.js`. Process I used was the following:

1. Add gem `'jquery-turbolinks'` to your `Gemfile` to fix turbolink javascript issue and `bundle install`
2. Add `jquery.turbolinks` to javascript manifest file:

   ```
   #app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require jquery.turbolinks
   //= require bootstrap-sprockets
   //= require turbolinks
   //= require_tree .
   ```
3. Go [here to copy the code for sorttable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js)
4. Create `js` file at: `app/assets/javascripts/shared/<whatever_you_want_to_call_it>.js`. Use `$(document).ready` as shown to fix turbo link problem.  Specify an IIFE (optional) then paste the vendor code within that IIFE:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     (function vendorTableSorter(){ 
       /* paste all the vendor code here */
     }());
   });// end document.ready
   ```
5. Then, simply add the class `sortable` to your table,which makes all the columns sortable:

   ```
   <table class=" table table-striped sortable">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
         <td><%= user.name %></td>
         <td><%= user.age %></td>
       </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
   ```

Answer (score 7):

## Fast - sortTable.js

**WARNING: if you plan to use pagination, this method will not work.**

The faster way (that takes zero queries) involves the library [`sortTable.js`](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/). The website does a great job explaining how to set your HTML document up. (Simply add some classes to column-headers.) You can also enable case-insensitive sorting.

Assuming you are using Rails 4, or have the turbolinks gem, I **highly recommend** following a [detailed gist with instructions](https://gist.github.com/onebree/efdf56929f63012ac85e) on setting up `sortTable.js` in your type on environment. (Full discussion can be found at my [Q&A on using turbolinks with sorttable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242006/how-to-enable-sorttable-js-on-rails4-with-turbolinks).)

---

## Reliable - custom controller methods

**WARNING: this method requires at least one query on every page view.**

This method comes from [Railscast 228: Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns). Reading the attached code is pretty much all you need. This method *does* work with pagination.

If you choose to follow [Railscast for pagination](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax), just stop *before* the Ajax part, as the Javascript involved is deprecated. Second, watch out for possible SQL injection in that screencast. Thankfully, it explains how to avoid it.

Comment: I reviewed all your links above. It looks like `sortTable.js` could be an option.  The frustrating thing is that bootstrap comes with lots of great javascript functionality already, including table sorting.  Since I am already using bootstrap on my project, I would prefer to use bootstrap instead of `sortTable.js`.  It seems like I'm just not doing something to include bootstrap's javascript functionality.  Any ideas?

Comment: In bootstrap, table sorting is _not_ column sorting, from what I understand. It is drag-to-sort, like rearranging priority of items in a list. We used the sorttable.js option for the company app, and we are using Bootstrap 3. We feel it is the best option.

Comment: They appear to be using just bootstrap here unless I am mistaken.  So it seems like it is possible? http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#sort-table

Comment: I would not recommend that method. It is not vanilla bootstrap, but rather added libraries. It has to be downloaded, and is not a gem. So any updates must be checked manually (instead of bundle install). It is also a lot more to maintain, code wise, than 1 javascript file (method #1).

Bootstrap is nothing more than prepackaged CSS and JavaScript to make a site responsive. Anything that is not vanilla bootstrap simply uses similar CSS or responsive concepts. Bootstrap is mainly for looks/motion of a web page, not function.

Comment: @Niel, let me know how option #1 works out for you. As noted, go to my Q&A about sorttable.js

Comment: works like a charm! I will add a temporary answer. Please copy it into your answer, and I will remove my temp answer and give you credit for the help!

Comment: ok please append my answer into your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83627/discussion-between-hunter-stevens-and-neil).

Comment: @Neil I sent you chat messages above. It does not look like you've replied to any.

Answer (score 7):

Using **bootstrap-sass** & **[bootstrap-table-rails](https://github.com/bjevanchiu/bootstrap-table-rails)** gems:

**`Gemfile`**:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails' # i'm not sure whether this is relevant
gem 'bootstrap-table-rails'
```

Don't forget to run `bundle` after you update your **Gemfile**.

**`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`**:

```
 //= require bootstrap-sprockets
 //= require bootstrap-table
 //  # Replace below with desired locale if needed
 //= require locale/bootstrap-table-ru-RU
```

**`app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`**:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-table";
```

**`app/views/index.html.erb`**:

```
<table data-toggle="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.age %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

FYI, my gem versions:

```
bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1
bootstrap-table-rails-1.8.2.1
```

Comment: `<thead>` is required.

Comment: and also [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) if you use [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) for ajax loading.

Comment: For now jquery.turbolinks [doesn't work](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/61) with Rails 5. You   should disable turbolinks for this page or remove it completely

Comment: @Evmorov or set version less then 5 `gem 'turbolinks', '< 5'`

Comment: @Evmorov, or not disable turbolinks, and actually learn how to use it w/ javascript/jquery. @installero, instead of using `$(document).on(load, function() {...});` use `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {...});`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table class=" table table-striped" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
    <th data-field="age" data-sortable="true">Age</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

 <tbody>
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
      <td><%= user.age %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried that but still not working for me unfortunately.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this example only works with [bootstrap-table-rails](https://github.com/bjevanchiu/bootstrap-table-rails) that is described in another answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Add *gem 'bootstrap-table-rails'* in your Gemfile and run bundle install.
2. Add *require bootstrap-table* in your application.js.
3. Add *require bootstrap-table* in your application.css.
4. Add *data-toggle="table"* to your table tag e.g. `<table data-toggle="table">`.
5. Add *data-sortable="true"* to your th tag e.g. `<th data-sortable="true">`. Make this property false if you don't want to sort any particular column e.g. `<th data-sortable="false">`